# How to get the list after splitting the string using splitPart in jOOQ?

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

I have a field tags which is a string formed by comma-separated strings.

When I try to get the data from the database I want them to be separated.

```
jsonObject(
.......
key("tags").value(splitPart(TABLENAME.TAGS, ",", 1))
.......
)
```

From the above, I can only get one value but I want the entire array.

What should I do to get the entire array after splitting?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [PostgreSQL `SPLIT_PART` function](http://Unfortunately,%20the%20PostgreSQL%20%60SPLIT_PART%60) doesn't allow for accessing the entire split array, only a "part". You probably want to use [`string_to_array`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/util/postgres/PostgresDSL.html#stringToArray(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) instead? That will produce a PostgreSQL array, which can be converted to a `JSON(B)` using the [`array_to_json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) function.

jOOQ does not yet support the latter (see [#12841](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12841)), but as always, when jOOQ doesn't know a vendor-specific SQL feature, you can easily resort to using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/).

Comment: Yeah I want to convert the string to array. But I want to do it which writing the query it self in JOOQ. How should I do it?

Comment: @SaiUttej: Did you click on the link of the `string_to_array` function?